# Function to check email on javascript doesn't work

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to check an email field on my website but the function that I have always returns false. The regular expression seems right but the function is not working properly.

Here is the code:

```
function CheckEmail(email)
{
//regular expression to check the email field
var expr = /^([0-9a-zA-Z]+([_.-]?[0-9a-zA-Z]+)*@[0-9a-zA-Z]+[0-9,a-z,A-Z,.,-]*(.){1}[a-zA-Z]{2,4})+$/;

if (expr.test(email)) {
    document.getElementById('alertEmail').innerHTML = '<img title="Valid Email" src="images/icoOk.jpg" alt="Ok"/>';
    f = true;
    return true;
}
else {
    document.getElementById('alertEmail').innerHTML = '<img title="Invalid Email!" src="images/icoErro.gif" alt="Erro"/>';
    f = false;
    return false;
}
}
```

any ideias??

Thank y'all so much for the help

Comment: How is the function called?

Comment: Your javascript function works fine, the problem is probably how you are calling it.  Try adding console.info(email) to see what you are passing in.

Comment: Please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function works fine if you pass a proper string to it, See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gvBEf/) to play with it.
try to output the email variable to the console or alert it to see the value:

```
console.log(email);
```

or

```
alert(email);
```

as the first line of your function.

Empty strings will always return false from your method.

Comment: In my page it always shows that the email is invalid :/

Comment: I tried to put the alert and it shows [objectHTMLInputElement]

Comment: By the way this is the input that I'm trying to get the email. It is an image that works as a textbox. When it gets the focus it just replace the image for another image without any text so the user can type the email

<td><input id="enterEmail" type="text" style="background: url(images/EnterEmail.png); width: 236px; height: 33px; color: white;" onfocus="showTextbox()"  onblur="CheckEmail(document.getElementById('enterEmail'))"/></td>

Comment: You need .value on the element to get the actual string value of the input. In your onblur try this: CheckEmail(document.getElementById('enterEmail').value)